# List comprehensions with arbitrary numbers of variables in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The problem I'm trying to solve is to get the set S which holds all the possible permutations of X number of integers such that all the integers are greater than 0 and when added are equal to some Y.

So, if X were equal to 2 and Y were equal to 5, the problem could be solved with this list comprehension:

```
[(a,b) for a in range(1,5) for b in range(1,5) if a+b==5]
```

However, I'm trying to solve for an arbitrary X and an arbitrary Y. I could write this as a gigantic series of if statements, but I feel like I'm so close to a nice, clean list comprehension to handle it. Is there any way to do this with list comprehensions?

Comment: Search for "integer partitions" (or "compositions", depending on whether you want to consider permutations equivalent).  Brute force will work but is *very* inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
[x for x in itertools.product(*variables) if sum(x)==5]
```

where variables is a list/tuple of your `range`s

Answer (score 2):

Sure. But you'll need [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) and [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).